# Multiple select insert only one value

Tags: php, mysql

The for loop updates only one record. It seems like it is not incrementing.

```
 <label for='Keys[]'>Select Keys</label>
<select multiple="multiple" name="Keys[]">
<?php
echo "<option value=''>Select A Key</option>";
$codesQuery=mysqli_query($DBcon,"SELECT * FROM Codes where Status != 'Used' AND UserID ='$ID'");
while($codes=mysqli_fetch_assoc($codesQuery))
{
echo "<option value='$codes[Value]'>$codes[Value]</option>";
}
?>
</select>      


$i=1;
    foreach ($_POST['Keys'] as $row => $printd) {
        $print_dim = $printd;
        $method = $_POST['method'][$row];

    $sql2 = "UPDATE `Codes` SET `Status`= 'Used' WHERE `Value` = '$print_dim'";



    enter code here

      $i++;
    }
```

Comment: I don't get this at all.

Comment: it pints 123412345Record updated successfully  but only 12345 is updated

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i need to update select keys in my database

Comment: your actual code don't update anythings  ..because  don't execute update

Comment: its down in the code.i just posted the query .sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so figured it out.. needed to put my query execute in my loop...

```
    foreach ($KeysS as $t) {

    echo "$t <br>";
  $sql2 = "UPDATE `Codes` SET `Status`= 'Used' WHERE `Value` = '$t'";
    if ($DBcon->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
         echo "Record updated successfully <br>";
    } else {
         echo "Error updating record: <br>" . $DBcon->error;
    }
}
```